Listbox с возможностью редактирования (через смену TextBlock на TextBox)
Нужен ListBox с возможностью редактирования. Здесь был совет реализовать через DataGrid, но выглядит не так как хотелось бы.
Разместил на ListBox друг над другом TextBox и TextBlock, по умолчанию виден TextBlock, по клику мышкой видимость сменяется на TextBox.
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Grid Width="280" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBox x:Name="tbNameService" Text="{Binding Name}" KeyDown="tbNameService_KeyDown" 
                        Visibility="{Binding IsEditing, Converter={StaticResource VisEditConverter}}" 
                        LostFocus="tbNameService_LostFocus" VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                        Width="270" IsVisibleChanged="tbNameService_IsVisibleChanged"/>
                    <TextBlock Name="tblNameService" Text="{Binding Name}" MouseDown="tblNameService_MouseDown" 
                        Visibility="{Binding IsBlocking, Converter={StaticResource VisBlockConverter}}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="270" />
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" Foreground="{Binding Color_status}" Width="140"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Naznachenie}" Width="220"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

Данные подтягиваются из класс, видимость тоже из этого же класса через конвертер bool-visibility.
В принципе все работает, но есть одна проблема: как сделать так чтобы менялась видимость по клику вне TextBox по любой области окна?

Проще запретить редактирование в TextBox и разрешать его по клику.

Через DataGrid действительно проще. А так, через стиль с тригерами на фокус или кнопку с карандашиком справа, всё через стили делается легко. Никаеие обработчики событий не нужны. А если уж решились логику во View писать, то юзерконтрол в помощь. так чтобы менялась видимость по клику вне TextBox по любой области окна? - потеря фокуса с текстбокса, я полагаю.

.NET 4.0 - ему больше 10 лет как устарел, почему такой древний фреймворк используете?

в некоторых конторах время остановилось к сожалению, поэтому .NET 4.0

@camtasia Windows XP? Серьёзно? Для семёры 4.6.1 катит вполне, он там предустановлен. И даже 4.7.2 вроде годится, если сервис-пак стоит.

Потеря фокуса срабатывает не на всех областях формы, поэтому и возник вопрос. Через "карандашик" это вместо клика по TextBlock вход в редактирование, а том что-то типа "лупы" -  просмотр?

XP и W2003(( есть еще такое

XP не поддерживает 4.0, по умолчанию там 3.5. 4.0 туда только насильно запихнуть можно предварительно накатив SP2 и кучу других обновлений. Я ошибся, 4.6.1 это Vista, на семёре 4.7.2.

Про карандашик - да. Можно карандашиком входить, галочкой выходить. Кстати, WPF на 4.0 сыроват, я бы не рисковал и использовал бы Winforms или SilverLight. А ещё круче, взял бы мощный .NET 8, и написал бы локальный HTTP сервер и скомпилировал бы его в нативное приложение (Native AOT), под XP были вменяемые браузеры (не считая MSIE).

А зачем тут "подмена"? Используйте просто TextBox у которого будет убран фон и убрана рамка, все, он будет выглядеть также, как и TextBlock, но с возможностью редактирования.

@EvgeniyZ верно, а по фокусу можно рисовать и рамку и фон, если хочется. Обычным стилем.
